# Why do I see strange characters when using “cat” on a zlib compressed file?

Tags: unix, compression

When I try to run the `cat` command on a zlib compressed file, I get this sequence of strange characters `xK??OR04d?H????/?I;{<%`

Where they come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used on a very basic level — such as `cat filename` — the `cat` command simply takes the contents of a file and writes them to standard output until the end of the file is reached.

A compressed document is effectively a binary file. Compression of text files makes them smaller in size but they are no longer text files after compression; they are now binary files.

So when you run a basic `cat` command against a binary file it will display the raw contents of that file directly and that is what the `xK??OR04d?H????/?I;{<%` is; compressed binary contents of a now compressed text file.

That said, in the case of binary files one can pipe the output of `cat` to another program that expects/uses binary input.

For example, if I have a text file named `textfile.txt` and I compress it with Gzip so the filename is now `textfile.txt.gz`, I can run this command to `cat` the file contents to `gzip` so I can read in in the terminal as a decompressed text file.

```
cat textfile.txt.gz | gzip -d -
```

Comment: Great edit!. It's now a much more useful answer :)